# Mavericks, Minecraft, Mods and Parental Controls

Tags: macos, permission

My son loves Minecraft and I have set up an account for him to play and it works fine with Parental Controls enabled.   Now he wants to add Mods to the game and I'm having a hard time getting the system to allow me into the proper folders to allow me to add the files he needs.  I need access to the ~\Library\Application Support\ folder.   I can access it with my administrator account but the one under my profile and not his.  I then shared his user folder with me on Read\Write but it says I don't have permissions.

Anyone else with this problem and were you able to solve it?   It is annoying me to no end.   I don't want to turn off parental controls if at all possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to open up Terminal.app for just a minute. This is what you should enter:

```
sudo chmod 777 '/Users/sandbox0/Library/'
sudo chmod 777 '/Users/sandbox0/Library/Application Support/'
sudo chmod -R 777 '/Users/sandbox0/Library/Application Support/minecraft'
```

Obviously, you'll need to change out `sandbox0` for your son's name, that was just the account I used to test it.

So what do these commands do?

- `sudo` means you'll be executing the command as root to ensure you have full permissions. You will need to enter your password the first time under a nice, big warning.
- `chmod` means “change mode” which will change the permissions of the file, with the `Library` folder, the `Application Support` folder, and finally with everything in the `minecraft` folder. (the `-R` means recursive, going through all the files and folders inside that one).

You may have to run the final command once in a while as new versions of Minecraft are downloaded and ready to be modded; a new JAR that Minecraft downloaded on his account will not allow you to edit it. If you will be doing this often, open the Applescript Editor, paste this in, and save as application.

```
do shell script "sudo chmod -R 777 '/Users/sandbox0/Library/Application Support/minecraft'" with administrator privileges
```